# Does Google Earth Engine (GEE) compute Vegetation Condition Index (VCI) time series correctly?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, vci

The formula to compute VCI from long term dataset is

`VCI= (NDVI_current-NDVI_min)/(NDVI_max-NDVI_min) * 100`, refer to [Drought monitoring using the Vegetation Condition Index (VCI)](https://www.un-spider.org/fr/book/export/html/9206)

```
Map.centerObject(geometry, 7);

var scaleMOD = function(img) {
        return  img
          .divide(10000)
          .float() 
          .set("system:time_start", img.get("system:time_start")); 
};



var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
            .map(scaleMOD)
            .filterBounds(geometry)
            .select('NDVI');
```

Let, months selected for VCI calculation are September and October from the year 2000 to 2010 (11 years time period).

```
var startyear = 2000; 
var endyear = 2010;
print ('no of years in study period', endyear - startyear + 1);
var startmonth = 9; 
var endmonth = 10; 
print ('no of months in study period', endmonth - startmonth + 1);
```

```
var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear, startmonth, 1);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear , endmonth, 30);
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear);
var months = ee.List.sequence(startmonth,endmonth);
```

```
var modis_list = [];
for(var i = startmonth; i <=endmonth; i++) {
  for(var j = startyear; j <=endyear; j++){
    modis_list.push(modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(j, j, 'year')));
  }
}
print(modis_list);
var modis_filtered_flattened = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(modis_list).flatten());
```

These are the monthly composites of NDVI using MODIS dataset `MOD13Q1`,

```
// NDVI composites for every month
var monthlyNDVI =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) { 
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var monthly = modis_filtered_flattened
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, "year"))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, "month"))
        .mean(); 
      return monthly
        .set("year", y) 
        .set("month", m) 
        .set("system:time_start", ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1).millis());}); })
  .flatten());
```

Here, the total no of monthly composite images of NDVI in the collections will be 22:-
11 of september and 11 of October from 2000 to 2010,

```
print (monthlyNDVI, 'monthly NDVI composites in study period = no of months * no of years')
Map.addLayer (monthlyNDVI.first().clip(geometry),  {min:0, max:1,  'palette': ['red','yellow', 'green']}, 'MonthlyNDVI')
```

The image having maximum pixel value of NDVI (max_NDVI) i.e containing the maximum value at each pixel in the raster generated from the time series of 11 years will be 2 (one for each month i.e september and october),

```
// Extract max values for each month over all years
var MonthlyMAX =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(months
  .map(function (m) {
    var maxNDVI = monthlyNDVI
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq("month", m))
      .select("NDVI")
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
      .rename("max_NDVI");
  return maxNDVI
    .set("month", m);})
  .flatten());
print (MonthlyMAX, 'MonthlyMAX no of images = no of months in study period');
Map.addLayer (MonthlyMAX.first().select('max_NDVI').clip(geometry),  {min:0, max:1,  'palette': ['red','yellow', 'green']}, 'MonthlyMAX')
```

Similarly, the image having minimum value for each pixel of NDVI in the raster (min_NDVI) will also be 2 (one for each month),

```
// Extract min values for each month over all years
var MonthlyMIN =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(months
  .map(function (m) {
    var minNDVI = monthlyNDVI
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq("month", m))
      .select("NDVI")
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
      .rename("min_NDVI");
  return minNDVI
    .set("month", m);})
  .flatten());
print (MonthlyMIN, 'MonthlyMIN  no of images = no of months in study period');
Map.addLayer (MonthlyMIN.first().select('min_NDVI').clip(geometry), {min:0, max:1,  'palette': ['red','yellow', 'green']}, 'MonthlyMIN')
```

As I am exporting the rasters, the script till here is working fine,
Like from all the monthly composites i.e `monthlyNDVI`
the value of `min_NDVI` and `max_NDVI` is being extracted as asked

i.e maximum value at each pixel in the raster out of 11 years time period in case of `max_NDVI` and same in case of `min_NDVI`

```
// Extract VCI for each month over all years
var vci_monthly = monthlyNDVI.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
 var min =  img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), geometry,250).get('NDVI');
 var max = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), geometry,250).get('NDVI');
 return img.expression(
   "((NDVI-min)/(max-min))*100",{
     "NDVI" : img,
     "max" : ee.Number(max),
     "min" : ee.Number(min)
   }).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

print(vci_monthly)
print (vci_monthly, 'vci_monthly composites in study period = no of months * no of years')
Map.addLayer (vci_monthly.first().clip(geometry),  {min:-100, max:100,  'palette': ['red','yellow', 'green']}, 'vci_monthly')
```

But I have doubt in case of VCI

Suppose if I want to compute the VCI of October 2005,

then `VCI_Oct_2005 should be = (NDVI_Oct_2005 - NDVI_min)/(NDVI_max-NDVI_min) * 100`

for example, in here, the VCI values generate by GEE is `VCI: 61.16399754930089` from the corresponding value of

`NDVI_Oct_2005: 0.4822999835014343`,

`NDVI_max: 0.7001000046730042`,

`NDVI_min: 0.4424000084400177`,

You will get these values in the inspector of the console, as you will run the script, and click on the raster layers.

Here, according to the calculations of the formula, the value of VCI should have been

`= (0.482 - 0.442)/(0.700 - 0.442) * 100 = ~15.5%`

[image: VCI]

But the GEE yield different results from it,

The script is here @ [VCI Script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1811da32494a27ff1b8f8a111df49f38)

***Where is the script wrong (if it is) or
which part of the my interpretation regarding VCI formula is wrong?***